# Image upload in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, file-upload

I need to upload image without use of any api ... I just need to upload it to base folder as we do in c# , is it possible and how ?

I tried many tutorials but all of them use api which is not my target

thanks in advance

Comment: Does this page help you?: https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-file-upload/

Comment: Do you want to upload a file ? or save a file somewhere ?

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler save the image in folder which will be accessible from local host or even server

Comment: @HOST-X this is use api which is not my target

Comment: You can't do that from the browser.